# Группы регекса охватывают первое и последнее совпадение, вместо каждых

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текст полученный с Genius, используя определенный скрипт я вставляю этот текст, заменяя **\n** на **<br>**. Текст с genius содержит в себе переходы (куплет, припев, дроп, обозначение автора, и т.п), вот два примера: [Куплет 1: Pyrokinesis] и [Куплет 2: найтивыход]

В полученном тексте их примерно 3-6, и мне нужно в тексте обозначить эти переходы с помощью  элемента с сменой цвета. Вот что я использую:

```
return val.replace(/\n/gm, '<br>').replace(/(\[.*\])/gm, '<b style="color: #FFEEF0">$1</b>')
```

По сути, \n меняется на br, что мне и нужно, а вот регекс подсветки ведет себя странно.
Дело в том, что тег b обхватывает весь текст, до последнего перехода ([Аутро: найтивыход]). В регулярных выражениях я не особо разбираюсь.

В общем: мне нужно чтоб было несколько совпадений, которые заменят только переходы, а не одно совпадение, которое обхватит начало и конец (задев текст).

Comment: Что если заменить `/(\[.*\])/gm` на `/(\[.*?\])/g`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Да, это сработало, спасибо. А можно обьяснение, почему обхват шел на весь текст, и что произошло теперь?

Answer (score -1):

надо менять не `\[.*\]`, т.к. это захватывает дословно символ `[` и жадно 0+ любых символов (кроме перевода строки по умолчанию) + символ `]`. Если надо до первой встречи `]` = нежадно, то так и писать -- `\[[^\]]*\[` -- символ `[` и 0+ любых символов, кроме `]` + символ `]`.

Ещё нежадный поиск включается с помощью `.*?`